# запуск второй активности по клику на пункт меню в android studio

Tags: android

Есть main_activity, которая работает с WebView, в этой активности есть меню (Три пункта), один из них "Помощь", который должен по нажатию вызвать вторую ативити (тоже с WebView). 
как прописать запуск второй активити по на нажатию на пункт меню?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ссылок и скриншотов, тут мало людей с знающих Arduiono

Comment: Как реализовано меню?

Comment: <item
    android:id="@+id/onlinehelp"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Онлайн руководство"
    android:onClick="HelpOnClick">
    </item>

Comment: Нужно по нажатию на "Онлайн руководство" выполнить переход к новой активити с WebView (адрес руководства).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределите метод `onOptionsItemSelected`, так как у вас несколько пунктов меню, он будет предпочительнее

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_help:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id. //и т.д
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

Да и не используйте `onClick` вовсе. Он в XML - ЗЛО!